# non-RESTful actions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

OK, while GitHub is down, a code design question:
I always get analysis paralysis with non-standard RESTful actions in rails apps (and generally).

I've got Jobs, and I want to be able to cancel (and re-activate) them. It's not as simple as setting a checkbox; there's a few other things that need to happen., so I can't just use the existing `JobsController#update` action.

Here are my options as I see it:

**1.** Just add `cancel` and `reactivate` to existing jobs controller.
The routes would be something like:

```
POST /admin/jobs/cancel/:job_id
POST /admin/jobs/reactivate/:job_id
```

*(Not RESTful; assuming this is a bad idea)*

**2.** Create a `JobCancellationsController` with `create` and `destroy` actions.
Re-activating a job is `destroy`-ing a `JobCancellation` resource.

I'll use nested routes as per below:

```
resources :jobs, except: :show do
  resource :job_cancellation, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

which by default will give me something like

a)

```
POST /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_cancellation
DELETE /admin/jobs/:job_id/job_cancellation
```

I could tidy the routes themselves up, without changing the controller, to be like:

b)

```
POST /admin/jobs/:job_id/cancellation
DELETE /admin/jobs/:job_id/cancellation
```

Although that doesn't seem very intuitive - 'cancellation' would be better as `cancel`. So I can change the routes while keeping the controller the same:

c)

```
POST /admin/jobs/:job_id/cancel
DELETE /admin/jobs/:job_id/cancel
```

That first route now makes sense (although it's not `RESTful` strictly speaking?), but the second doesn't... "deleting a job cancel"? So you'd change it to something like:

d)

```
POST /admin/jobs/:job_id/cancel
POST /admin/jobs/:job_id/reactivate
```

Now the routes makes sense, but look suspiciously close to option 1) above, even though the routes do map to RESTful actions in the `JobCancellationsController` rather than non-RESTful actions in the `JobsController`. And it seems very bizzare to have the `POST /admin/jobs/:job_id/reactivate` route mapping to the `JobCancellationsController#destroy` action.

To avoid that last odity with `JobCancellationsController#destroy`, I could instead do:

**3.** Similar to option 2, but create two controllers: `JobCancellationsController` with a `create` action only, and `JobReactivationsController` with a `create` action only.

What's the 'correct' way to do this? Or at least, which are the 'incorrect' ways that I can quickly eliminate? Is there a totally different, better way that I've missed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a discussion on the Ruby Australia slack channel, I've consolidated the advice into the below:

**The Answer**

Just add `cancel` and `reactivate` to the existing `JobsController`.

Use this code:

```
resources :jobs do
  post :cancel, on: :member
  post :reactivate, on: :member
end
```

to create routes like:

```
POST /admin/jobs/:job_id/cancel
POST /admin/jobs/:job_id/reactivate
```

This is simple and intuitive, even if it's not strictly RESTful.

(Another advised approach was to PATCH to the existing `update` method with a status of cancelled; though I guess that'd require a conditional in your update method for `cancels` vs regular `updates`)

**Other useful points that came out in the discussion**

- resourcing things that aren't resources is a common trap when you're being sold "REST is the best!" (ie, `Jobs` are a resource, but `JobCancellations` aren't really, so don't try to make them a resource).
- If you don't need the ability to delete a job, you could use the `destroy` action to cancel jobs instead of a `cancel` action.
- IMO going full REST is only useful in certain contexts that you aren't likely to encounter unless you're at a big corp.
- Make an API that makes sense. Rails just provides ways to do CRUD stuff easily. That ties in to restful but isn't all of it.
- the REST (or HATEOS) way to do it is to have `/jobs/1234.json` include a `cancelLink: {url: "url", method: "POST", rel: "link to the docs"}` property
- when we were building our API we had an unofficial rule that if we weren't sure what to do, we'd just copy what github do, as we like their API.
- fwiw, I’ve used a bunch of "rest" APIs that were well designed according to rest, but horrible to use as a developer. It’s more important that you A) cover primitives and B) make it friendly to use than you abide by REST (or HATEOS, or whatever you're focusing on today) all the time.

All of the above basically points to advice I always try to tell myself: "It's most important that the code is simple and easy to understand. Design patters are useful only to the extent that they help you achieve that goal. If a design pattern doesn't achieve that goal, it's likely you're using it incorrectly, or applying it to an incorrect situation, or following it too rigidly".

Comment: I really appreciate this writeup, especially the last paragraph. More informative than just an answer. I've been criticized for just the approach you've decided on a number of times by devs who think that only REST is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case why not just have

```
# Cancel a job (handled by your cancellations controller)
DELETE /admin/jobs/:job_id

# Likewise, reactivate a job if so instructed by the request body
PATCH /admin/jobs/:job_id
```

There's a lot of potential to run in to the general "you're not doing REST right" debate that I don't think I really care to get into; this particular case looks like it has a decent solution.

FWIW, do you really need to allow reactivation of the same job? It might be more clear to require creating a new job once cancelled. Perhaps offering some mechanism to clone an existing job.

Comment: Thanks. I had a good discussion about this on the Ruby Australia slack channel. The advice wasn't far off yours, but had some extra info worth knowing. I'll consolidate it into an answer soon.

And BTW, yeah, definitely need reactivations.

Comment: Several things. (1) Cancel is the wrong word; call it deactivate. (2) JobCancellation is not a resource, but a task/action. (3) I'd argue that the resource is the "active" flag, nested under Job - set it true or false.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense cliffordheath. So then would you have a JobActiveFlagsController?

Comment: I don't know if you can assume it's as simple as a flag; cancelling a job may very create some resource of note that more closely matches the semantics of creating something or at least is more grand than a flag e.g. you may log the user that cancelled it, the time it was cancelled, such that even my suggestion of using `delete` does not accurately represent the resource.