# Keeping controllers RESTful in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, controller

Say I have a Loan resource in my app. It can be accepted or rejected by a user. I could add `accepted` and `rejected` actions to my `LoansController`, but is there another option that will keep my controller RESTful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few approaches.

You could have a `LoanAcceptances` controller with a `create` and `destroy` action - that is, rejecting a loan is "destroying a loan acceptance". That's counter-intuitive, but does keep your controllers "RESTful".

You could have a `LoanAcceptances` controller with a `create` action and a `LoanRejections` controller with a `create` action - that is, rejecting a loan is "creating a loan rejection". And now you have two controllers with just a single method.

Or, you could just put them both in `LoansController` as `accepted` and `rejected`. This violates the design principle of "REST" but adheres to common sense.

You'll find people willing to argue to the death for either approach - but don't get too caught up in it. Either will work. If you're finding your `LoansController` is getting an ever-increasing proliferation of methods (eg. `accept`, `reject`, `mark_pending`, `apply_interest`, `make_payment`, etc), then perhaps it's worth pulling them out and going the "separate controllers" approach.

If you're not finding that, it's fine to keep it simple and put them in the same controller.

Some time ago I asked a similar question which you'll find interesting to read: [non-RESTful actions in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051278/non-restful-actions-in-rails)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.